# Is there a way to prevent write access violation when inserting elements to the back of a Dynamic Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic

I want to use the `insertBack()` function to add elements to the back of the array; but, I get an error when I try to do so:

> Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation. this->arr was
>   0x1110116.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong; my professor's post and pre-conditions are just confusing to me. I also don't know how allocate is used and if my way of doubling the capacity is even correct.

**Container Class:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class container
{
    template <typename T2>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const container<T2> &cobj);
    // Postcondition: contents of the container object cobj is displayed
public:
    container();
    // Postcondition: an empty container object is created with data members 
    // arr set to NULL, n set to -1 and Capacity set to 0
    ~container();
    // Destructor; required as one of the Big-3 (or Big(5) because of the 
    // presence of a pointer data member. Default version results in 
    // memory leak!
    // Postcondition: dynamic memory pointed to by arr has been release back to 
    // the “heap” and arr set to NULL or nullptr
    // In order to see the action, message "destructor called and 
    // dynamic memory released!" is displayed
    bool isEmpty() const;
    // Postcondition: returns true is nothing is stored; returns false otherwise
    bool isFull() const;
    // Postcondition: returns true if arr array is filled to capacity; 
    // returns false otherwise
    int size() const;
    // Postcondition: returns the size or the number of elements (values) 
    // currently stored in the container
    int capacity() const;
    // Postcondition: returns the current storage capacity of the container
    bool insertBack(const T& val);
    // Postcondition: if container is not full, newVal is inserted at the 
    // end of the array; 
    // otherwise, double the current capacity followed by the insertion
private:
    void allocate(T* &temp);
    // Postcondition: if Capacity = 0, allocate a single location; 
    // otherwise the current capacity is doubled
    T *arr;
    int Capacity;   // Note: Capital 'C' as capacity is used as a function name
    int n;          // size or actual # of values currently stored in the container; 
                    // n <= SIZE
};
```

**Function Definitions/Code:**

```cpp
template<typename T2>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const container<T2> &cobj)
{
    std::cout << "Currently it contains " << cobj.size() << " value(s)" << std::endl
        << "Container storage capacity = " << cobj.capacity() << std::endl
        << "The contents of the container:" << std::endl;

    if (cobj.isEmpty())
    {
        std::cout << "*** Container is currently empty!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=0; i<cobj.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::cout << cobj.arr[i];
        }
    }

    return out;
}

template<typename T>
container<T>::container()
{
    arr = nullptr;
    Capacity = 0;
    n = 0;
}

template<typename T>
container<T>::~container()
{
    delete arr;
    arr = nullptr;
    std::cout << "Destructor called! (this line is normally not displayed)" 
              << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
bool container<T>::isEmpty() const
{
    return n==0;
}

template<typename T>
bool container<T>::isFull() const
{
    return n==Capacity;
}

template<typename T>
int container<T>::capacity() const
{
    return Capacity;
}

template<typename T>
int container<T>::size() const
{
    return n;
}

template<typename T>
bool container<T>::insertBack(const T& val)
{
    if (size()>=Capacity)
    {
        Capacity = Capacity*2;
        n++;
        arr[n] = val;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void container<T>::allocate(T* &temp)
{
    if (Capacity==0)
    {
        temp = new T;
    }
    else
    {
        return Capacity*2;
    }
}

int main()
{
    container<int> a1;
    std::cout << a1 << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "Currently, the container object contains 0 element(s) or 0 value(s)" 
              << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\nWe now insert 3 values at the back of the array, one at a time:" 
              << std::endl;

    const int num = 3;
    for (int i=0, c=0; i<=num; ++i, c+=10)
    {
        a1.insertBack(c);
    }

    std::cout << a1;
}
```

Comment: `container<T>::insertBack` doubles the `Capacity` value but doesn't actually allocate any additional memory.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I could get rid of the isempty and isfull functions, hmm.

Comment: It _does_ compile. Running: `Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core` That was from `clang++`. `g++` does not compile it.

Comment: @walnut It's full of nasty. `clang version 9.0.1` compiles it. `valgrind` catches the stuff I mentioned. `g++` refuses.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh, it actually does. This seems like a very obvious bug. I am surprised that clang had it (there is an error now with Clang 10), even with `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: @walnut I'm always surprised when this stuff passes my Stackoverflow Makefile. I compile everything with `g++` and `clang++` and with `clang++` I go for `-Weverything -Werror` ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo do u mean the code for the container class? i was thinking about getting rid of the post and pre-conditioons, but i could fix the spacing

Comment: @S.Coughing It's readable now! :-) ... but this is not what I compiled 40 minutes ago, is it? `g++`: https://pastebin.com/4vbaQ7by
`

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks, i didn't change anything in the code: it's the same--maybe my way of changing the formatting may have had some effect?

Comment: Ok: `template<typename T>
void container<T>::allocate(T*& temp) {
    if(Capacity == 0) {
        temp = new T;
    } else {
        return Capacity * 2;
    }
}
` This function sometimes return `Capacity * 2` - but ... is `void`. That alone makes your program have undefined behavior.

Comment: It is perfectly valid and safe to have a `void` function `return` a `void`, even a `void` return value of another `void` function. This is explicitly allowed by the standard, to handle templates that may have to deal with `void` types.  Now, returning a non-`void` value from a `void` function (as this code is doing) is definitely not allowed, though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, of course. I have deleted my misleading comment. In any case `return Capacity *2;` in `allocate` which is declared `void` is ill-formed and should result in a compiler diagnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `insertback()` and `size() >= Capacity`， your array does not really expand. You just double the variable named `Capacity`, but the array itself is not actually doubled.

You can try this code to double your array as followed:

```
T* old_array = arr; arr = new T[Capacity<<=1];  //double array
for(int i=0;i<n;++i) arr[i]=old_array[i]   //copy you can use memcpy instead for loop
delete [] old_array;    //free space
```

There are some other errors found in your code:

1. Destructor

   You should use `delete []arr` instead `delete arr`.

   `delete` frees the memory to which a **single object pointer** to new is allocated.

   `delete []` frees the memory that the newly allocated **object array pointer** points to.

   And remember to check if arr is nullptr before using delete.
2. `insertback`

   Use `arr[n]=val;` before `n++;`.
3. `void container<T>::allocate(T* &temp)`

   The return type of `allocate()` is **void**. Therefore you cannot `return Capacity*2;`.

Tip:

I recommend setting a default capacity for `Container`. So when the capacity is not specified, request the default capacity space instead of setting the capacity to zero.

Comment: For setting the capacity to default for the container, should i not assign 0 to it--just leave it declared? I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what's happening here `new T[Capacity<<=1]` inside the brackets.

Comment: `new T[Capacity<<=1]` means `Capacity = Capacity*2; new T[Capacity]`. Request double memory to replace old one. Set default capacity can avoid some corner case like you want to double memory but 0*0 is still 0, and you want to delete arr but arr is nullptr. In default constructor, you can use `arr = new T[default_capacity];`. I think it saves lots of troubles.

Comment: "*you can use memcpy instead for loop*" - if the container's array does not contain elements that are a trivial type then using `memcpy()` is unsafe to copy the elements. You can use `std::copy()` instead, which will always "do the right thing" to copy elements based on their actual type, and it will use `memcpy()` internally if it is safe to do so.